# Category of Monads on $PreOrd$

Tags: category-theory, higher-category-theory, monads

In a recent paper by Adamek ("Finitary Monads on the Category of Posets", see it on Arxiv) the author introduces the category of finitary monads on $Pos$ and analyzes it in great detail. More in general, if we take preorders (i.e. the category $PreOrd$) instead of posets, we can consider the category of monads on it. If I don't go wrong, its Hom-sets are actually small sets, so we do not need to limit to finitary monads. Well, my question is if such a category has been already studied or if its investigation is still pending as an open problem. If it has been already studied, can you provide me some references on such a topic?

Comment: Why do you think the hom sets are small?

Comment: There is very little difference between the category of pre-ordered sets and of posets. Do you expect the theory of monads on pre-orders to be significantly different than on posets?

Comment: There are some differences, however. For example, the forgetful functor from preordered sets to sets has a right adjoint, but the forgetful functor from posets has no right adjoint.

Comment: @ZhenLin Actually, there is no reasoning for thinking it, you're right. However, to answer to the other comments, though the are minimal differences, these differences can be very interesting and GeoffreyTrang provided one. So, I imagine that he knows some references on the topic.

Comment: Certainly there are differences. Every preordered set is canonically isomorphic to a poset. The lack of a right adjoint is pointing to a difference between the two categories as concrete over sets. So, when considering ordered structures, one can forget first to the underlying ordered sets, and then to sets, or just to sets in one go. Here there would be a difference between forgetting ordered structures all the way to sets, vs. forgetting pre-ordered structures (the latter will tend to have a right adjoint). However, for monads, I don't see this difference as being too relevant.

Comment: @IttayWeiss You mean "equivalent", not "isomorphic", since "equivalence" and "isomorphism" of categories (of which preorders are a special case) have slightly different meanings.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang Yes, thank you, I meant canonically equivalent (with the emphasis on the canonicity).